# AIX mkuser with group name as username

Tags: security, aix

I'm running a bunch of AIX systems and I would like to change the way in which users are created.

By default users are made with the group assignment (both primary and only group membership) as staff. I would like to set this to $USERNAME.

I took a peek in to the /etc/mkuser.default file and it sets the home directory by doing /home/$USER so I tried reusing the $USER variable for the pgrp and groups variables, however it returns saying that the group doesn't exist when I try to create a user.

Does anyone know if this is at all possible? A viable solution would be for a custom script to be run upon creation of a user, however mkuser.default appears to only read the variable settings within the user stanza.

Thanks all,

Ian.

Comment: This seems offtopic to me. Maybe superuser.com would be a better fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the group should be present before you add the user to it. Hence, you may try writing a shell script like this to create users:

```
#!/bin/ksh
user_name=$1
if [ -z "$user_name" ]
then
    echo "No Username specified"
    return 3
fi
mkgroup $user_name || {
    echo "mkgroup $user_name failed";
    return 4;
}
mkuser pgrp=$user_name $user_name || {
    echo "mkuser $user_name failed";
    return 5;
}
```

and execute it like:

```
./create_user.sh red
./create_user.sh blue
./create_user.sh green
```

**Make sure you are removing the groups you have created while you are deleting the users**

So the shell script to remove the users may look like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
user_name=$1
if [ -z "$user_name" ]
then
    echo "No Username specified"
    return 3
fi
rmuser $user_name || {
    echo "rmuser $user_name failed";
    return 4;
}
rmgroup $user_name || {
    echo "rmgroup $user_name failed";
    return 5;
}
```

I'm looking into the mkuser.default file thing. To my knowledge **mkuser.default** is picked up from **/usr/lib/security** folder in AIX 7.1

**Another thing to note:** The home directories /home/ will still be there when you remove the user and the group. If you are creating usernames/groups with the same names make sure you do something like:

```
chown -R <username>:<groupname> /home/<username>
```

after creating the user again.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My hope was to try and do it through the standard admin procedures but it seems my hopes and dreams are not to be realised.